# How do I change bunch of filename in one shot?

Tags: shell, cygwin

I have several `xml` files which I want to batch-rename. I can not use the `rename` command.

E.g.

```
CN_GG121509_176321-29956-2014-04-16-05-07-20.xml
CN_GG121509_176321-29956-2014-04-16-05-08-22.xml
```

should be renamed to

```
CN_GG121509_176321-29956-2014-04-16-05-07-20_reprocess1.xml
CN_GG121509_176321-29956-2014-04-16-05-08-22_reprocess2.xml

-----------------
CN_GG121509_176321-29956-2014-04-16-05-08-22_reprocess11112.xml
CN_GG121509_176321-29956-2014-04-16-05-08-22_reprocess11113.xml
```

from reprocess(N) `N` should be dynamically updated.

I tried the below command

`find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'mv $1 "${1_reprocess%.xml}.xml"' {} \;`

but that did not work.

**EDIT**

It is worked with below command

`for FILE in *.xml; do mv "$FILE" $(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/\.xml/_reprocess\.xml/'); done`

Comment: Why can you not use `rename`? What "did not work"?

Comment: I am using `cygWin` in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" | while read file; do  mv "$file" "${file%.xml}_reprocess.xml"; done
```

To add a counter at the end of the filename:

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" | { i=0; while read file; do 
  mv "$file" "${file%.xml}_reprocess${i}.xml";
  let $[i++];
done; }
```

(You can write it in one line)

Comment: Can we dynamically apply the value to filename ? Like reprocess1, reprocess2. reprocess3 etc ?

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.xml}_reprocess.xml"' {} \;
```

`${1_reprocess%.xml}.xml` in your example would remove the trailing string `.xml` from the variable `${1_reprocess}` (and append `.xml`) which is why it does not work.

EDIT:

```
#!/bin/bash    
i=1
for file in *.xml; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
    mv "${file}" "${file%.xml}_reprocess${i}.xml"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Can we dynamically apply the value to filename ? Like reprocess1, reprocess2. reprocess3 etc ?

Comment: @Sahal Based on what? This is not part of your problem description so please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Sahal It's still not clear at all where the number comes from. Do you just want an increasing counter starting from `1`?

Comment: Yes, you are rite. It should increase the counter

Answer (score 1):

You can use this find:

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec bash -c 'f="${1%.xml}"; echo mv "$1" "${f}_reprocess.xml"' - '{}' \;
```

**EDIT:** Base on comments:

```
i=0
while read -r f; do
   (i++))
   mv "$f" "${f%.xml}_reprocess${i}.xml"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.xml")
```

Comment: Can we dynamically apply the value to filename ? Like reprocess1, reprocess2. reprocess3 etc ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" | sed 's/.xml//' |  xargs -I % mv % %_reprocess.xml
```

Comment: Can we dynamically apply the value to filename ? Like reprocess1, reprocess2. reprocess3 etc ?

Comment: @Sahal I think for that purpose, one of the other suggestions with a loop in bash will work better for you